# Using data from pgAdmin with a python script

Tags: python, pgadmin, osrm

Hi I am trying to write a python-script where I call coordinate-data from my pgAdmin database and use this data in a curl request (with the OSRM-engine) to generate a number of routes.

My problem is getting getting one set of coordinates at a time into my Curl request and running the curl request with each specific set of coordinates. That should give me a lot of routes but it's not working.

```
import psycopg2
import requests

conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host = "localhost",
            database = "Test_Mads",
            user = "postgres",
            password = "NotThis")

cur = conn.cursor()

adresse_data = cur.execute("select * from koordinater")

adresse_data = cur.fetchall()

print(adresse_data)


x_skole = 55.64924
y_skole = 12.50325

x = [item[1] for item in adresse_data]
y = [item[2] for item in adresse_data]


#solution 1 

for coordinates in adresse_data:
    r = requests.get('http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{0},{1};{2},{3}?geometries=geojson'.format(x_skole, y_skole, coordinates[1], coordinates[2]))

#solution 2

for coordinates in range(len(x))
    r = requests.get('http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{0},{1};{2},{3}?geometries=geojson'.format(x_skole, y_skole, x[coordinates], y[coordinates]))

    myjson = r.json()
    print(myjson['routes'][0]['geometry'])
```

[image: pgAdmin]

[image: First Solution result]

[image: Second solution result]

Comment: `for coordinates in range(len(x))` is missing a colon: `for coordinates in range(len(x)):`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing the colon (":") after "for coordinates in range(len(x))"

Comment: True, thanks! Now I just get the same answer as the first solution (which is better but still not what I am looking for!